# Create a sequence in a matrix

Tags: r

I need a sequence of vector indices in a matrix if the length of vector is 40

```
 x <- 1:40
```

Output I expect is

```
     1   11   21
    11   21   31
     2   12   22
    12   22   32
     3   13   23
    13   23   33
     4   14   24
    14   24   34
     5   15   25
    15   25   35
     6   16   26
    16   26   36
     7   17   27
    17   27   37
     8   18   28
    18   28   38
     9   19   29
    19   29   39
    10   20   30
    20   30   40
```

Comment: This needs more details, what you're providing isn't enough for someone to help you with.

Comment: What in the world do you need this for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your `x`

```
matrix(mapply(c, head(x, -10), tail(x, -10)), 20, 3)

#       [,1] [,2] [,3]
#  [1,]    1   11   21
#  [2,]   11   21   31
#  [3,]    2   12   22
#  [4,]   12   22   32
#  [5,]    3   13   23
#  [6,]   13   23   33
#  [7,]    4   14   24
#  [8,]   14   24   34
#  [9,]    5   15   25
# [10,]   15   25   35
# [11,]    6   16   26
# [12,]   16   26   36
# [13,]    7   17   27
# [14,]   17   27   37
# [15,]    8   18   28
# [16,]   18   28   38
# [17,]    9   19   29
# [18,]   19   29   39
# [19,]   10   20   30
# [20,]   20   30   40
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
 matrix(rep(1:10,each=6) +c(0,10,20,10,20,30),ncol=3,byrow=T)
```

Comment: so elegant! This is better than mine :)

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
mat <- matrix(c(0,10,20,10,20,30),nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)

res <- lapply(1:10,function(n) mat + n)

do.call(rbind,res)
```